# Track Progress for Video Uploading on iOS with Rails Server

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, carrierwave

I am a newbie with Ruby on Rails and right now I am building an API for uploading a Video to my Rails Server. I have built my uploading API with Carrierwave. This is actually going well with me. However on the iOS side, I need to be able to track the video uploading progress. I need pro on Rails to give me an advice on how to do this on my Rails API or maybe on the iOS app. Also, I am getting a Timeout on NSURLConnection while uploading the video which is kind of a problem for me.

Rails API Code Snippet

```
    data = params[:business_asset][:video].to_s
    io = BusinessVideoString.new(Base64.decode64(data))
    io.original_filename = "foobar.mp4"
    io.content_type = "video/mp4"
    @business_asset.video = io

    if @business_asset.save
      render :json => { :video => @business.business_asset ,:message => "success"},:status => 200 
    end
```

On the iOS Side, I am using NSURLConnection methods

```
   - (void) postRequestFromUrl: (NSString *) urlString withDictionary: (NSDictionary *) post{

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSError *error;
        NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:post options:0 error:&error];
        NSString *  postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

        //url where u will send data
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody: postData];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postLength length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

        NSURLConnection * conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        if(conn) {
            NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
        } else {
           NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
        }
   }
```

Any advice on how should I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the send data and total data using the following delegate,

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
   didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten
 totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
```

Reference : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite: